# Shiny: What is the correct syntax to write reactive custom functions (performing operations on dataframe columns)?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, shiny, scope

I am trying to build my first Shiny app.
I have created a custom function taking several input parameters and returning a dataframe.
Then, the dataframe is used to produce a ggplot.

The goal of the Shiny app is to let the user play with the input parameters.
The output are (1) the dataframe returned as a table, and (2) the ggplot returned as plot.
The UI consists of simple numerical inputs to select the values of the parameters of the custom function.

The function `myfunction` is separated in the `helpers.R` file. Here is the code:

```
myfunction <- function(a=10, b=10, c=20){
  column1 <- seq(1, a, by=1)
  dataframe_results <- data.frame("column1"=column1)
  
  dataframe_results <- cbind(dataframe_results, b)
  dataframe_results <- cbind(dataframe_results, c)
  
  ## calculation of the results
  dataframe_results$column2 <- NA
  dataframe_results$column2 <- b*log(column1)

  dataframe_results$column3 <- NA
  dataframe_results$column3 <- dataframe_results$column2*c+b
  
  return(dataframe_results)
}
```

The problem is that the reactive expression used on the custom function leads to an error.
The function works perfectly outside of the Shiny app, but when it is in the app, I obtain:

`Warning: Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 0 rows, data has 5`

I think it might be a scope issue, but the placement of my function seems correct.
I tried to place the function at different locations:

- first element of the server section.
- within the `renderPlot` and `renderTable` functions.
- at the beginning of the script, before the UI section.

Here a reproducible example of the shiny app code:

```
#    Libraries
library(shiny)

#  Helper function
source("helpers")

#  Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("input_a", "Parameter a", value=5),
      numericInput("input_b", "Parameter b", value=10),
      numericInput("input_c", "Parameter c", value=20)
      ),
    mainPanel(       
      tableOutput("dataframe_results"),
      br(),
      plotOutput("graph_results")
    )
  )
)


#  Define server logic
server <- function(input, output){
    
    user_run <- reactive({
      myfunction(a = input$input_a,
                 b = input$input_b,
                 c = input$input_c
      )
    })
    
    output$dataframe_results <- renderTable({
      user_run()
    })
    
    output$graph_results <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data=user_run(), aes(x=column1, y=column3))+geom_line(size=1)
    })
  }
  
#  Run the app
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

This all seems to work fine, but not when I run my own code (which has more inputs than this simplified example). The error points to the line:

`dataframe_results$column3 <- dataframe_results$column2*c+b`

I believe it could be a problem of scope, related to the fact that a dataframe column is used, but I am not sure.
Unfortunately, I have not shared my full script because is a bit too long, but I have essentially simplified the logic to the example above. I can share it completely if that can help.
The error really points at this line, but with this simplified example it works, so I don't see what is the difference between my example and my own code (it is essentially the same logic).
I have searched for two days but couldn't find a solution for a similar question.

Could you tell me how to properly write and position a custom function doing operations on a dataframe for a Shiny app?

Comment: It’s not scoping. Reactives are updated when the app first loads. Inputs are not defined at this point. Add req(input$input_a, input$input_b, input$input_c) at the start of your user_run reactive and you should be fine.

Comment: @Limey, thank you for your advice. I followed your advice by placing `req(input$input_a, input$input_b, input$input_c)` in the reactive function before calling `myfunction` but now the app does not display the outputs. No error message anymore but no output...

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  With the addition of `library(ggplot)` (and my `req()` statement) to your MWE, I get a table and a graph.

Comment: Sure, sorry if my question is not clear. The example I am presenting is not the actual script I have. The example works fine (actually with and without `req(input$input_a, input$input_b, input$input_c)`), but if I replace each component of the example with my script, I obtain an error message. The thing is that each component works well when it is not wrapped in shiny. I will create a new question with the entire script.

Comment: @Tom, as your MRE works fine, perhaps you should try `dataframe_results$column3 <- b*c*log(column1) + b` in your `myfunction` with real code.

Comment: I think it is important to share the error message that you receive. What is it?